# how to take a date as an input and insert it in a table while doing sql connectivity in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have tried doing some sql connectivity and  faced a problem recently, i could'nt take isert dates into a table. I have given the code below. what should i add in this?

```
import mysql.connector as con
db = con.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "root", database = "vish")

if db.is_connected():
    print("success")
a = int(input("roll no. : "))
b = input("name : ")
c = int(input("phone : "))
cursor = db.cursor()
q = ("insert into student values({}, '{}', {})".format(a,b,c))
cursor.execute(q)
db.commit()
```

## how do i take date and insert it into a table

Comment: Is there any error message involved? I don't see where you insert a date value in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table `t` and a column `c` and you wish to insert a date literal, the format for that literal is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, so for example:

```
INSERT INTO t(c) VALUES('2020-01-11')
```

But whenever you are getting input from the "outside", you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attacks and should be using prepared statements. If you have parsed the input date and built a string literal such as `'2020-01-11'` from the input, then you are safe. But if you have isolated the year, month and day and you are using a prepared statement anyway because there are other values you have not so rigorously validated, you can also use a `'?'` parameter for the date thus:

```
from datetime import date

today = date(2020, 1, 11)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t(c) VALUES(?)", (today,))
cursor.commit()
```